# Rename tag "santa" to "santa-claus"

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

We currently have a tag [santa](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/santa) on the main site.

I'm simply proposing that it be renamed to [santa-claus](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/santa-claus).

Comment: Is this just an *OCD* thing or does this actually solve any problems you've encountered? Just asking; I don't judge *OCD* things, it's what I do all the time

Comment: As a non-native English speaker, I really think it's a good idea. That satan/santa post a few days ago really puzzled me.

Comment: @PatJ Well, they both dress in red, and figure out who's naughty and who's nice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no reason not to, and as PatJ points out in a comment, this can help our readers who are not native speakers of English.  Done.